# "From - Till" vs "From - To"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, range-inclusion

I read an experience letter which said

> "So and so" person has worked **from** "date1" **till** "date2".

Is it okay? Or should it be like this?

> "So and so" person has worked **from** "date1" **to** "date2".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either construction is fine.

In my mind using *to* is preferable, but *until* or *till* are acceptable alternatives.

There are examples in literature:

> [God has worked from those beginnings until now](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5DbZAAAAMAAJ&q=%22has+worked+from%22+until&dq=%22has+worked+from%22+until&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AEiRT7DlGMK-0QWZ7sXfAQ&redir_esc=y)
>   [she has worked from ten o'clock at night until noon the next day](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FCxHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22has+worked+from%22+until&dq=%22has+worked+from%22+until&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bEiRT57FHIjM0QWn1fDkAQ&redir_esc=y)
>   [He has worked from four in the morning until late at night](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I7tDAQAAIAAJ&q=%22has+worked+from%22+until&dq=%22has+worked+from%22+until&hl=en&sa=X&ei=40iRT_bTJqPD0QWtg5j6AQ&redir_esc=y)
>   [has worked from 6 till now](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XCsaAAAAYAAJ&q=%22has+worked+from%22+till&dq=%22has+worked+from%22+till&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TkmRT9D_OeLA0QXp1Mz8AQ&redir_esc=y)

*Till* and *until* are synonyms in this context. They mean "up to a specific point in time" ([see: ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/until)). I would say that they are more likely to be found with simple (clock) times, rather than dates, but are not incorrect to use with dates.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that you can use both, but that in some cases there can be a very slight difference in meanings regarding whether `date2` is included or not. I don't have any evidence to base this on and it may be my background as a programmer that makes me say this, but I would say that for the first example ("date1 *until* date2"), especially if there is an emphasis on the "until", it sounds as though something happened on `date2` to exclude it from the interval, whereas it's included in the second example ("date1 *to* date2", i.e. "date1 up to and including date2").

Being Australian, I would consider "till" to be rather informal, but I believe that in American English it is perfectly acceptable as an alternative spelling to "until".

Comment: +1. Your instinct is right. You should find and include some references, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I regard "from....till" as a function of time whereas "from....to" as a function of space.

Comment: Can you offer any links or sources to support this usage as something standard, or is it just your personal usage?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/from%20dawn%20to%2Funtil%20dusk): 'from dawn to/until dusk (idiom)' //// And from [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+dawn+to+dusk#:~:text=Fig.,to%20produce%20hats%20and%20gloves.):   'from dawn to dusk Fig. during the period of the day when there is light; from the rising of the sun to the setting of the sun. _I have to work from dawn to dusk on the farm._  / _The factory runs from dawn to dusk to produce hats and gloves._